# What is the Radius of 1 and 1/4 inch drill on a 1 and 1/4 Circle

Tags: drafting, autocad

I have this figure for my engineering drawing I am currently taking this semester I am quite baffled about this $1\dfrac{1}{4}$ radius circle with $1\dfrac{1}{4}$ Drill hole. How do I do that? as a reference I have this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1-1/4 drill is a reference to the *diameter* of the drill. The hole will have a radius of 5/8.

Answer (score 0):

The answer with 5/8 radius is irrelevant.  Well not completely.  Could help find answer.

The leg has a 1 1/4 in hole in it.  Therefore the leg with a 1 1/4 radius will be a 2.5 inch dia leg half way rounded.

Now.  How long and wide is your actual part?